# @aws-sdk/client-lambda] - Invoke Lambda - Payload Response in Unit8Array - Convert to String

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am using the `@aws-sdk/client-lambda` npm package for invoking lambdas. I have two Lambdas. Lambda A & Lambda B. Lambda A is trying to invoke Lambda B.

Lambda A invokes Lambda B by running the following code:

```
const { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lambda');

module.exports = {
  getGitHubToken: async () => {
    const client = new LambdaClient({ region: process.env.REGION });

    const params = {
      FunctionName: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN_FUNCTION,
      LogType: 'Tail',
      Payload: '',
    };

    const command = new InvokeCommand(params);

    try {
      const { Payload } = await client.send(command);
      console.log(Payload);
      return Payload;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  },
};
```

The expected response from Lambda B should look like this:

```
{
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    token: '123',
  }),
};
```

However, Payload looks to be returning this from the line `console.log(Payload);`:

[image: Response]

I looked on the [AWS SDK Website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/modules/invocationresponse.html#payload) and it looks like `Payload` returns a `Uint8Array`. I guess this is because it's from a promise?

I have tried doing `Payload.toString()` however that comes back as simply a string of the values in the `Unit8Array`. Example being:

```
2021-04-13T14:32:04.874Z worker:success Payload: 123,34,115,116,97,116,117,115,67,111,100,101,34,58,50,48,48,44,34,98,111,100,121,34,58,34,123,92,34,116,111,107,101,110,92,34,58,92,34,103,104,115,95,111,114,101,51,65,109,99,122,86,85,74,122,66,52,90,68,104,57,122,122,85,118,119,52,51,50,111,67,71,48,50,75,121,79,69,72,92,34,125,34,125
```

**My Question:**

How do I resolve data from `Unit8Array` to the data I was expecting from the Lambda response? Which is a JSON Object?

I have confirmed the requested Lambda (Lambda B in this case) is returning the data correctly by going to CloudWatch. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I found a way to get this working.

You have to specify a text encoder:

```
const asciiDecoder = new TextDecoder('ascii');
```

Then decode it so it looks like this:

```
const data = asciiDecoder.decode(Payload);
```

I have logged an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2252) on their repository asking why this isn't included in the module. I will post an update on any movement on this.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2252#issuecomment-822960768) from the GitHub issue logged by the OP, if you are using Node.js you can use this approach.

```
const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(Payload));

// if using TypeScript 
const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(Payload).toString());
```