# Read Uint8Array in a Json Object in Typescript When Processing AWS Lambda Response

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have the following json that I get when I invoke an AWS Lambda.

```
{
'$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '1245',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  ExecutedVersion: '$LATEST',
  Payload: Uint8Array(4) [ 110, 119, 106, 108 ],
  StatusCode: 200
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a valid JSON because of the`Payload`. How can I read the value inside the payload here? Appreciate any advice.

I tried the below way, but getting "undefined" when I print `backendResponse`.

```
const res = await client.invoke(command).then((data: InvokeCommandOutput) => {
            if (data?.FunctionError || data === undefined) {
                console.error('Error calling the backend lambda:', data);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    console.log("data", data);
                    const backendResponse = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(data.Payload!).toString('utf-8'))
                    console.log("Response from lambda", backendResponse);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error('Error parsing backend lambda response', err);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67092958) to a similar question, that should help. There's also more information at the [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2252) mentioned in the question.

Comment: I tried the solution there, but still getting NULL :(